# Graph generation of bamboo builds

Tags: javascript, html, graph, bamboo

I am a c++ programmer and new to bamboo.
I have many repositories which are compiled daily as part of CI in Bamboo as different plans.
I want to represent these build state in a graph. (dynamic updating)

Bamboo provides graph of build status for each plan. But not as a whole.
Or is there any facility available?

So, my idea is to write the build status of each plan into a file & then read that file to generate the graph. i.e at any time if I open the graph, it will show me the status by reading that file.
[image]
So, my question is:

- Is this possible what i am going to do?
- If yes, then is there any way bamboo has inbuilt in it?
- If no, can you suggest me how to achieve this? (i know a bit of html & js)

Comment: Bamboo does have two APIs: PythonAPI and RestAPI that you can use to read build status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the APIs that tmlai mentioned in comments above to get the data and use D3.js to render the graphs in a web page.

I do not know if bamboo has that functionality built in.